# SLF4J and Logback: Propagate logger to autowired services

Tags: java, spring, logback, slf4j, autowired

I'm kind of new to Logging, and I've started a project for which I've chosen Logback.

I have the following `logback.xml` configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="BARLOGGER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME:-/repository/logs}/bar.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME:-/repository/logs}/bar.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="BOOLOGGER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_HOME:-/repository/logs}/boo.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME:-/repository/logs}/boo.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.foo.bar" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="BARLOGGER" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.foo.boo" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="BOOLOGGER" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

I have 2 services (`Boo` and `Bar`), in two different packages. I have configured an appender for each of them, and the logging for those services works fine.

This is the problem I'm facing.

Both services (`Boo` and `Bar`) have an autowired dependency of a third service (`Tee`), for which there is no appender defined. The `Tee` service is located on `com.foo.tee`

I do not want to have a unique log for the 3 services, as they do different things and run at different times.

Is there a way to include `Tee` service logging to Boo or Bar appenders, depending on which service (`Boo` / `Bar`) called this service ?

**Basically, what I want to achieve is**

- **Bar has a Tee dependency. If Bar calls a Tee method, that method's logging should be written to Bar logger only**
- **Boo also has a Tee dependency. If Boo calls a Tee method, that method's logging should be written to Boo logger only**
- **Bar and Boo logs write to different files, and Tee logging should only be appended to its "invocator" log**

I would want this to have context for the operation being performed, as having a third logfile for Tee makes it difficult to trace where a call came from.

Thanks!

PS: I tried to find a previous answer to this, but I don't know if I was searching with the wrong keywords or if this cannot be accomplished.

Comment: not really sure what is going on, but if you install lombok to your project, all you have to do to get logger is annotate class with @Slf4j. look into it, good luck.

Comment: @Sarief a bit overkill as it only replaces a single line `private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())`

Comment: @OrangeDog maybe, but for me it was like: install and use. also no need for thsi line, as it in my opinion is overkill :D

Comment: Service "Tee" has the proper private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tee.class), but for some reason, the logging from Tee is not being included neither on Bar or Boo logs. That is what I'd like to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've configured three loggers

- com.foo.bar
- com.foo.boo
- root

If you're wanting some class not in the bar/boo package to use the bar/boo logger, then you'll need to not use its own logger.

```
class Tee {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bar.class);
```

Note also, that logger names don't actually need to actually correspond to any package or class name.

If you want the logger to depend on the caller, then the call should include a logger.

```
class Tee {
    public void doSomething(Logger log) {
```

Comment: So, Logback cannot determine the logger to use depending on who called Tee, right ? In this case, if Boo calls Tee, Tee logging will be outputted to Bar log.

Comment: The logger this is used is the logger that you use. There's no magic anywhere.

Comment: Thanks @OrangeDog, I was just trying to find out id that ind of magic existed, cause I'm kind of new into logging frameworks and something like this would have been very useful for me. I was already planning on use your suggestion, but wanted to know if there was something to avoid it. Thanks!